# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to api.keen.io port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: php, keen-io

Our API code recently started failing to push events to one of our two Keen IO projects.

We are using identical code in each case except with different API keys. I even tried to regenerate the keys without any luck.

The error thrown by Guzzle which is called from the PHP keen-io/keen-io libraries is:

`There was an error executing the addEvent command: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to api.keen.io port 443: Connection timed out` (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being a network routing issue. The server that was failing could not make requests to other APIs either, nor could the Linux OS even perform software updates which require a connection to external package repositories. It turns out when we moved to the new building, somehow the same IP address got assigned to two servers, which was somehow creating outbound request issues. Once that was resolved this issue went away.

(The only other reason writes would fail to one Keen IO project but not another is if the project was blocked for some reason. But, in that case, the API would return a 429 or other more descriptive error, not a 443.)